# Switching between worksheets

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create a `xlsx` file from `csv`. Each line in this csv contains attribute 'ATR'. Many lines can have the same attribute 'ATR', for example 'x','y' etc.

So what I want to do is to go throug csv file lines one by one and write them into this xlsx file. If there is no worksheet with the name as a value of attribute 'ATR', create it and write this line there. It there is already this worksheet, write the line into this worksheet.

```
def temp_file_to_xlsx():
    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('export.xlsx')

    with open('export/export.csv') as f:
        r=-1
        for row in f:
            r+=1
            data = {}
            splitted_row = row.split('::')
            for column in splitted_row:
                splitted_column = column.split('.:.')
                data[splitted_column[0]]=splitted_column[1]

            ws = wb.add_worksheet(data['ATR']) # IT SAYS THAT THERE IS ALREADY WORKSHEET WITH THIS NAME SO I WANT TO WRITE IT THERE
            attributes = data.keys()
            for c in xrange(len(attributes)):
                try:
                    ws.write(c,r,data[attributes[c]])
                except:
                    ws.write(c,r,'-')
        wb.close()
```

Is it possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to note all the worksheets you create and re-use them.
For example, at the start of your function, create a dictionary:

```
sheets = {}
```

Then replace the line:

```
ws = wb.add_worksheet(data['ATR'])
```

by

```
if not sheets.has_key(data['ATR']):
    sheets[data['ATR']] = wb.add_worksheet(data['ATR'])
ws = sheets[data['ATR']]
```

hence keeping all the previously created worksheets and reusing them.